# xslt enable-disable control

Tags: xslt

I have 2 control : Check box and Choice (Radio Button).
On Selecting check box , radio field should be enabled and on unchecked of check box , choice field should be disabled.

Can someone help with it!!!

Code as follows

```
<tr>
    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel"><H3 class="ms-standardheader"><nobr>Survey Confirmation<span class="ms-formvalidation">
        <xsl:text xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" ddwrt:whitespace-preserve="yes" xml:space="preserve">   </xsl:text></span></nobr></H3>
    </td>
    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
        <xsl:variable name="FormField1Checked">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@surveyconfirmation='1' or msxsl:string-compare(string(@surveyconfirmation),'Yes','','i')=0 or msxsl:string-compare(string(@surveyconfirmation),'True','','i')=0">true</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>false</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" id="FormField1{$Pos}" text=" " checked="{$FormField1Checked}" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('FormField1',$Pos),'Checked','CheckedChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@surveyconfirmation')}" />Yes
    </td>
</tr>                   
<tr>
    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
        <H3 class="ms-standardheader"><nobr>No of Days</nobr>
        </H3>
    </td>
    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
        <SharePoint:formfield runat="server" id="ff28{$Pos}" controlmode="Display" fieldname="Survey_x0020_Confirmation_x0020_" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff28',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Survey_x0020_Confirmation_x0020_')}"/>

    </td>                   
</tr>
```

Comment: what did you try? what error did you get? Which version of SP?

Comment: SP2010. I tried to do it using javascript but not able to do.

Comment: not actually an answer, but you may try with customizing the list form with InfoPath. This will allow you to define custom rules, like enabling controls if a requirement is met. However, you will need the enterprise CAL licence (you did not specify the edition of SharePoint).